# Центрировать текст относительно ромба

Tags: html, css, center

Подскажите, как его отцентрировать, чтобы как на фото было?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.zaslugi_icons {
  width: 140px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 48px;
  padding-left: 39px;
  padding-right: 18px;
}

.zaslugi_icons p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
}

.zaslugi_icons span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="zaslugi_icons">
  <img src="img/icons_1.png" alt="">
  <p>Реализованных <span>проектов</span></p>
</div>
<div class="zaslugi_icons">
  <img src="img/icons_2.png" alt="">
  <p>Положительных <span>отзыва</span></p>
</div>
<div class="zaslugi_icons">
  <img src="img/icons_3.png" alt="">
  <p>Лет <span>опыта</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Автор вопроса, если вам помог чей-то ответ, не забудьте отметить его решением=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без псевдо элементов

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.unit {
  background: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}

.over {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.unites {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.unites .vois {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="unites">
    <div class="unit">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="over">
        <p>75</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="vois">Наши отзывы</p>
  </div>

  <div class="unites">
    <div class="unit">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="over">
        <p>115</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="vois">Выполненые работы</p>
  </div>

  <div class="unites">
    <div class="unit">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="over">
        <p>180</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="vois">Количество благодарных клентов</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="unites">
    <div class="unit">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="over">
        <p>75</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="vois">Наши отзывы</p>
  </div>

  <div class="unites">
    <div class="unit">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="over">
        <p>115</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="vois">Выполненые работы</p>
  </div>

  <div class="unites">
    <div class="unit">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="over">
        <p>180</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="vois">Количество благодарных клентов</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Самый простой вариант с псевдо-элементами:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: div;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white, inset 0 0 0 5px gray;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

div::after {
  counter-increment: div;
  content: counter(div);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>lorem</div>
<div>ipsum</div>
<div>dolor</div>
```

Comment: плюсик от меня , удобный пример , но с псевдо элементами опередил ты меня, пришлось переделать

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, да, и не нужно много прописывать всего

Comment: да но зато динамично всё делать сложно когда псевдо элементами